# git: how to revert file which is in .gitignore [fatal: empty commit set passed]

Tags: git, symfony

My .gitignore file has the following line

```
vendor/
```

I have modified a file inside the vendor folder. 
Now when I do update my bundles by performing -

```
bin/vendors install
```

- I see the following message

> "Bundle name" has local modifications. Please commit or revert/push them before running this command again.

I realize that I should have not changed anything in bundles and am trying to correct that mistake.

When I try to revert the file by issuing the command:

```
git revert <path>/<filename>.twig
```

I get this error message

> fatal: empty commit set passed

`git rm` doesn't work either.

How can I make my bundle install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either:

1. Revert the file you changed to its initial state:

   ```
   git checkout path/to/file
   ```
2. Remove the `vendor/` directory and run `bin/vendors install` again. That way you are sure everything is new.

A rule of thumb of thumb is that should **NEVER** modify files in the `vendor/` directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: git checkout path/to/file doesn't work - I have already tried that. It says "Error: pathspec path/to/file did not match any files known to git.
Instead of deleting the entire bundles directory I'll just remove that particular bundle and try.

Comment: Worked, I removed only that 1 bundle. Running bin/vendors install, successfully cloned that bundle thereafter.