# GitLab excludes some folders from commit in Symfony2 project

Tags: git, symfony, windows-7, repository, gitlab

For some reason, GitLab ignores the contents of some folders in my "vendor" folder in a Symfony2 project. I have deleted all .gitignore files in the entire project, except for one in the root folder where I have inserted a line stating that the entire vendor folder should be included:

```
!vendor/*
```

However, still not all files in vendor are synced with the repo. So the team members are running out of sync with each other and configurations obviously start failing.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm using http://git-scm.com for a client on a Windows7 machine.

Comment: Does your `git status` show you what you want, before you start pushing?

Comment: Did you try a `!vendor/` (without the '`*`'). By the way, this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9153563/6309) indicates nothing should be changed in `vendor/` ;)

Comment: Do you have a global `~/.gitignore` in your home directory?

Comment: @VonC: yes, the status is ok.