# git commit gives error: empty commit set passed

Tags: git, github

When trying to revert to a previous commit, I tried:

```
git revert --no-commit 0766c053..HEAD
```

However this gave an error:

```
empty commit set passed
```

**Question:** What does the error mean, and what went wrong with the `revert` command?

Comment: Have you tried with git reset --hard <commit-id>?

Comment: @jailani that ***does not*** do the same thing as what the original poster is trying to do.

Comment: I found this, but I'm not sure if it's related: [git: how to revert file which is in .gitignore [fatal: empty commit set passed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153540/456814).

Comment: Can you provide us with a history tree? Maybe you misunderstood the functionality of the double dot syntax. You can take a closer look [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

Answer (score 8):

Remove the ..HEAD part. At least on my system (git v2.7.4) this resolved the issue.

> git revert --no-commit 0766c053

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you misused the `double dot` annotation to specify a commit range.

So your range doesn't return any commits which means that `revert` can't do anything, since you effictively said "*revert no commits*".

The [gitpro book](http://git-scm.com/book) explains the [`double dot` annotation (link to chapter)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_commit_ranges) pretty solid:

> The most common range specification is the double-dot syntax. This basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable from one commit but aren’t reachable from another. For example, say you have a commit history that looks like Figure 6-1.
>
> [image: Figure 6-1. Example history for range selection.]
>
> You want to see what is in your experiment branch that hasn’t yet been merged into your master branch. You can ask Git to show you a log of just those commits with `master..experiment` — that means "all commits reachable by experiment that aren’t reachable by master." For the sake of brevity and clarity in these examples, I’ll use the letters of the commit objects from the diagram in place of the actual log output in the order that they would display:
>
> `$ git log master..experiment`
>   `D`
>   `C`
>
> If, on the other hand, you want to see the opposite — all commits in `master` that aren’t in `experiment` — you can reverse the branch names. `experiment..master` shows you everything in `master` not reachable from `experiment`:
>
> `$ git log experiment..master`
>   `F`
>   `E`