# revert changes to a specific commit

Tags: git

I created a new branch just for myself and now I need to revert multiple commits at once from the master branch to a specific commit. I know there's a safe command to use `git revert --no-commit COMMIT_TO_REVERT_FROM..COMMIT_TO_REVERT_TO`

this gives me `error: empty commit set passed
fatal: revert failed`

What should I do ?

Suggested solutions here on SO were no use.

Comment: Wild guess: did you swap the begin and end commits by accident?

Comment: No, they're in the right order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit gives error: empty commit set passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730127/git-commit-gives-error-empty-commit-set-passed)

Comment: Did you try a dry run with a simple git log (and same range) to output the commits to revert? Is the list as expected?

Comment: `git log COMMIT_TO_REVERT_FROM..COMMIT_TO_REVERT_TO` gives me nothing. Nada. The commits exist though, I can see them in the repo.

Comment: @Mark "Some" commits exist, yes. But the range `A..B` means "every commit reachable from B but NOT from A". I guess there are no such commits in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example graph to rule out your "empty range" error

```
A---B---C---D---E---F
```

Let's say your `COMMIT_TO_REVERT_FROM` is `F`, and `COMMIT_TO_REVERT_TO` is `C`.

```
git log F..C
```

should output `D`, `E` and `F`.

I'd recommend triple-checking (in reference to Quentin's comment) these two ends have not been swapped by mistake (which is rather common since the syntax of ranges is counter-intuitive to many). (Sorry if it's not the case, but it was worth a few minutes to rule it out completely.)

Comment: I appreciate it but that was the first thing I checked. Whether or not I swapped commits by accident. I didn't.

Comment: `git log COMMIT_TO_REVERT_FROM..COMMIT_TO_REVERT_TO` should give me about 20 commits but I'm getting nothing. That's weird. I see all those commits in the repo.

Comment: Can somebody else from the team revert the changes or it can do the person who made the commits only ?

Comment: @Mark Anyone (with rights on the repo of course) can.

Comment: That should be `C..F`: include F-on-back, but exclude C-on-back, leaving F then E then D.

Comment: @torek I get same error. This is a super mystery I'm telling you. Common command that works for majority but me.

Comment: @Mark: at this point I'd look for some sort of environmental effect. For instance, do you have `$GIT_DIR` set in your environment? Is your `.git` a conditional symlink on an OS like that on the old Pyramid systems? etc.