# Erasing commits using web ui

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to erase multiple commits from repository. I'm using BitBucket. Is there a way to do it from web user interface ? I'm asking because

`git revert --no-commit COMMIT_TO_REVERT_FROM..COMMIT_TO_REVERT_TO`

hasn't worked for me. It gives me error:
 `error: empty commit set passed fatal: revert failed`

Output from `git log`:

```
* 8e84dad (HEAD -> mareks-branch, origin/master, origin/mareks-branch, 
origin/HEAD, master) working on retrieving relevant test cases for a
particular test suite. Is not working correctly just yet * 03df960 
Simple Data Modelling
```

Here it is clear that git is aware the two commits in question.

Can I do it from ui ?

Comment: I remember your [revert issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693597/revert-changes-to-a-specific-commit). I'm afraid it will be as difficult to help you here for the same reasons, you didn't show a lot about your current history. Could you post something to help figure? Like the output of `git log --oneline --graph --all --simplify-by-decoration`, or a git GUI screenshot / a bitbucket screenshot of your recent commit tree?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't say it explicitly, but it would be far handier in the question body rather than in comments.

Comment: I'm actually thinking of stop using git because it's too much headache and wasted time. Instead of doing actual work I'm dealing with commits. Waste of time.

Comment: Honestly, I don't believe you can do such specific work under bitbucket. I think you have to do it locally.

Comment: @mnestorov Well, I wish. `git revert --no-commit` supposedly works for exactly this purpose but it's not working in my case. I'm gonna probably have to get the book "Git Pro" just to understand this issue and resolve it.

Comment: Luckily it's [free](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) :). I am not sure why this is happenning. I guess that the other answers from your other post and the related links didn't work :/

Comment: That's what is frustrating about this. I went through other topics on SO as well and the command worked one way or another for majority of cases.